# please provide solution for below errors laravel

Tags: laravel

Need to use variable in where clause.

```
$eventid = Event::select('id')->orderBy('startdate')->where('startdate','>', now())->take(1)->get();
$event = Event::find($eventid);      
$speaker = Speaker::all()->where('event_id', '=', $eventid);

return view('event')->with('event', $event)->with('speaker', $speaker);
```

**output:
Events Table Data:
10 asdfsfdg 2019-10-02**

When I use below code I am able to get proper output.

```php
$eventid = Event::select('id')->orderBy('startdate')->where('startdate','>', now())->take(1)->get();
$event = Event::find($eventid);      
$speaker = Speaker::all()->where('event_id', '=', **10**);

return view('event')->with('event', $event)->with('speaker', $speaker);
```

**output:
Events Table Data:
10 asdfsfdg 2019-10-02
Speakers table data:
6 test ste**

Please can you correct above code to display with variable in where condition.

Answer (score 0):

You are pulling in a **collection** for your `$eventid` variable in this line:

```
$eventid = Event::select('id')->orderBy('startdate')->where('startdate','>', now())->take(1)->get();
```

`$eventid` is a collection of **Event** objects numbering in total 1.  To get the id of the *first* event after your start date, try the following:

```
$event = Event::where('startdate','>', now())->first();
$eventid = isset($event)? $event->id : 0;
```

You could chain this and put the id at the end (`->first()->id`), but you may not have an event after this starting date, and thus it would fail.

The difference in this answer vs your original code, is that by using `first`, you pull a single object that will have an `id` field.  Doing it with `get()` as you did, it will be a collection, and not have an id field, and thus will fail your `where()` method on the **Speaker** query.

Note, you may also wish to revise the query parameters.  The way you have it now, and the way I wrote it with `first()` will give you the first event after the startdate. You may want something further down the line if you have multiple events. You could add more detail on the query if this is the case.

Comment: when I use first(), i am getting below error.

Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ani\resources\views\event.blade.php)
Previous exceptions

    Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (0)

Comment: is there any version issue? i am using v5.8.35

Comment: Yes, this is exactly why I separated out the `$event` call from `$eventid` in my answer.  You may not have an event after the startdate, and it will then be null.  Thus, the `isset` check in the next line of my answer.  Please see the last paragraph of my answer as well - this code will work, but only if you have something in the database.  Otherwise, you will have an `id` of 0 using this answer - which you can then account for later using a check (`if($eventid == 0) { // handle the null $event here }`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$eventid` variable is a collection. `find` works fine to get you the instance of the model but in where clause you are supplying collection instead of a variable. and thus it's not working. And why are you using `get` and then `find`?? use simply `first`

```
$event = Event::where('startdate','>', now())->orderBy('startdate')->first();
$speaker = Speaker::where('event_id', '=', $event->id)->get();
return view('event',compact('event','speaker'));
```

Comment: When I use above code it is displaying below error. please can you help me.

 ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ani\resources\views\event.blade.php)
Previous exceptions

    Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (0)